# Faceted search and heat map creation on GPU

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I am trying to find ways to filter and render 100 million+ data points as a heat map in real time.

Each point in addition to the (x,y) coordinates has a fixed set of attributes (int, date, bit flags) which can be dynamically chosen by the user in order to filter down the data set.

Would it be feasible to accelerate all or parts of this task on GPUs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you were more specific, but I'm assuming that you want to apply a user specified filter to the *same* 2D spatial data. If this is the case, you could consider organizing your data into a spatial datastructure, such as a [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or K-d tree.

Once you have done this, you could run a GPU kernel for each region in your datastructure based on the filter you want to apply. Each thread will figure out which points in its region satisfy the specified filter.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, this is the kind of problem that fits into the GPGPU spectrum.

You could decide to create your own kernel to filter your data or simply use some functions of vendor's libraries to that end. Probably, you would normalize, interpolate, and so on, which are common utilities in those libraries. These kind of functions are typically embarrassingly parallel, at it shouldn't be difficult to create your own kernel.

I'd rather use a visualization framework that allows you to filter and visualize your data in real time. [Vispy](http://vispy-website.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a great option but, of course, there are some others.